# How to add GROUP BY command when defining tableDefination in QueryBuilder (node.js)

Tags: javascript, node.js

I am using QueryBuilder in nodejs where I declare tableDefination which is an object. In this object i define selectSQL, formSQL and whereSQL . My question is how to add GROUP BY command at the end of the query. I tried to to add it in whereSQL but QueryBuilder adds a ")" at the end of whereSQL so it is eventually giving execution error. Below is my code.

```js
 whereSql += " && tb_cdta_driver.cdta_id = " + cdta_id;"

var tableDefinition = {
            sSelectSql: " count(tb_engagements.engagement_id) as rides, " +
                " tb_cdta_driver.driver_id, " +
                " tb_cdta_driver.driver_name, " +
                " tb_cdta_driver.driver_phone, " +
                " tb_cdta.cdta_name ",
            //DISTINCT
            sFromSql: " tb_cdta_driver  JOIN tb_engagements ON tb_cdta_driver.driver_id = tb_engagements.driver_id JOIN tb_cdta ON tb_cdta_driver.cdta_id = tb_cdta.cdta_id ", // added tb_session himadri
            sWhereAndSql: whereSql,

            aSearchColumns: ["tb_cdta_driver.driver_id"],
            // NASEEF: Added is_pos, appr_code and card_digits 
            sCountColumnName: " tb_cdta_driver.driver_id ",
            aoColumnDefs: [{
                mData: "driver_id",
                bSearchable: true
            }
            ]
        };
```

Comment: I solved it by adding below code before running the query. I hope it might help.

  `var requestQuery = req.query;
   var queries = queryBuilder.buildQuery(requestQuery);
    queries = queries.join(" ");
    var stringOperation = queries.toString().indexOf("ORDER");
    queries = [queries.slice(0, stringOperation), "GROUP BY 
  tb_cdta_driver.driver_id ", queries.slice(stringOperation)].join('');`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I solved it by adding below code before running the query. I hope it might help.

`var requestQuery = req.query; var queries = queryBuilder.buildQuery(requestQuery); queries = queries.join(" "); var stringOperation = queries.toString().indexOf("ORDER"); queries = [queries.slice(0, stringOperation), "GROUP BY tb_cdta_driver.driver_id ", queries.slice(stringOperation)].join('');`